# Как защитить запрос от изменения?

Tags: php

Есть блок уведомлений с кнопками котрые имеют id записей при нажатии на кнопу открывается пост. Например как видно на скрине есть кнопка с data-id="274" если нажать на нее то в базу аяксом передастся id 274 и выведется запись с этим id.
Проблема в том, что если пользователь введет через консоль разработчика другое значение например 555 то выведется запись с id 555. Мне нужно сделать так, что бы даже если пользователь изменит id то все равно выводилось 274. Как это можно сделать. Я пробовал сделать так в инсте или в вк и там работает так как я хочу. Надеюсь на вашу помощь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы можете писать в куки данные (при открытии к примеру страницы) и от туда пересылать их на сервер, ведь куки пользователь не сможет изменить через инструмент

Comment: исходная проблема то в чем? не дать пользователю просмотреть чужие записи? пользователь авторизован? да. ID  в сессии храните? вероятно да. Посты с пользователем связаны? очевидно, да. вот и пишите запрос `where id = :postId and user_id = :uid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте объект в js и id для каждой кнопки при первой загрузке страницы парсите всё в этот объект. А потом уже берете значения непосредственоо с него. 
Например в самой примитивной реализации:

```
<div class="wrap"> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="show_post_notify_btn_274" class="show_post_notify_btn" data-id="wallid_274"></a>
</div>

<div class="wrap"> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="show_post_notify_btn_278" class="show_post_notify_btn" data-id="wallid_278"></a>
</div>

<div class="wrap"> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="show_post_notify_btn_280" class="show_post_notify_btn" data-id="wallid_280"></a>
</div>

<div class="wrap"> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="show_post_notify_btn_290" class="show_post_notify_btn" data-id="wallid_290"></a>
</div>

<script>
    (function($){

        let postLoader = {
            postButtons : {},

            init: function()
            {

                this.prepareData();

                this.events();
            },

            prepareData: function()
            {
                $('.show_post_notify_btn').each(function(index, el) {
                    postLoader.postButtons[$(el).attr('id')] = $(el).data('id');
                });
            },

            events: function()
            {

                $('.show_post_notify_btn').on('click', function(event) {

                    var key = $(this).attr('id');

                    var id = postLoader.postButtons[key];


                    postLoader.send(id);
                });

            },

            send: function(id)
            {

            },


        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            postLoader.init();
        });

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но выдает ошибку `Uncaught ReferenceError: el is not defined`

Comment: Исправил. Этот код написал быстро от руки, так что ничего не тестил. Просто дал Вам пример в какую сторону можно было бы копать.